# Problem with calculated member in Schema Workbench

Tags: pentaho, saiku

I have the Formula:

```
(([Measures]. [QuantityPathology])/([Measures]. [QuantityPersons],
 [DimPathology.Pathologies].[All])) * 100
```

The numerator is the measure QuantityPathology and the denominator is the QuantityPeople grouped by the member All of the hierarchy Pathologies, that is the total number of people served in that period regardless of the selected pathology.

But it does not work, since saiku analysis does not display any results, which may be doing wrong.
Modify message

Attached is an example of the formula

```
(([Measures], [QuantityPathology])/([Measures], [QuantityPeople],
 [DimPathology.Pathologies][All])) * 100
QuantityPathology with Bronchitis year 2019 = 61
Number of people served in the year 2019 = 4569

61/4569 = 0,013350843*100 

Result =1,3350843
```

Also `avg(NumberPeople)` does not work in all rows returns 1

I don't have any error in catalina.out

Thank you very much.